# 30 persons, 3 related readouts

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I am stuck with how to best analyze the following experimental design:

We analyze 3 variables (A, B, C), that are not independent from each other: if one of them is high, the other ones are expected to be rather high, too (and vv), but not equal. The basic question we want to answer is, if B or C is different from A (higher or lower, i.e .null hypothesis: A=B, A=C), in an individual person. In different persons, however, different orders are possible: e.g. (1) AB, A and  n.s.; (3) ...  In other words, we do NOT suggest that e.g. A>B in general, but want to identify the persons with A>B, AC, AB in 20 % of persons. I.e., we have 2 kinds of statements:

1. Can (A=B & A=C) be rejected in A GIVEN INDIVIDUAL person? If so, which (B, C) differs from A?
2. A > B in ...% of persons, A < B in ...%, A > C in ...%, A < C in ...%, give e.g. confidence intervals (for this Q only as far as correction for multiple testing is concerned)?

For experimental reasons, A, B and C are measured repeatedly (~3-5 times, on 3-5 days, i.e. day 1: A1, B1, C2, and day 2: A2, B2, C2, and day 3: A3, B3, C3 ... ) per person. Technical variability is expected to affect A, B, C equally on a given experimental day, i.e. it makes sense to analyze as paired samples.

There are about 30 different persons, that do NOT belong to different groups, but are just subsequent persons in whom we test our null hypothesis individually for that person.

So far, we used Quade tests per person (repeated measures for 3 variables): ca. 1/3 has significant differences in A vs B or A vs C.

Questions:

(A) Does it make sense to correct for multiple testing (persons 1-30 so far)? (For statement 2 (aggregate percentages) and/or for statement 1 (individual person)? What happens if we increase the number of persons - wouldn't that (I feel paradoxically) decrease the likelyhood of a positive test in an individual person? Would e.g. Holm be appropriate, or rather FDR (Benjamini Hochberg) since we are interested in the percentage of positives (not necessarily which one exactly)? Or is this even too much, since it is just a PERCENTAGE, and not a list of e.g. DIFFERENT genes from microarray?

(B) If necessary to control for the number of persons - is there a better analysis than individual tests + correction for multiple testing afterwards?

As suggested, I include a reproducible dataset (`dfSample`) here:

```
set.seed(12345) # get reproducible random numbers

n <- 30  # number of persons

lSet <- list(
  # Niveau of the readout values for each person (arbitrarily set for readout A)
  base.level = runif(n = n, min = 10, max = 100),         
  # readouts for B and C are similar, but not equal, i.e. factors e.g. in the range of 1/2 to 2)
  factors = data.frame(                                   
    A = 2^runif(n = n, min = log(x = 1/1,   2), max = log(x = 1,   2)),  
    B = 2^runif(n = n, min = log(x = 1/1.5, 2), max = log(x = 1.5, 2)),
    C = 2^runif(n = n, min = log(x = 1/1.5, 2), max = log(x = 1.5, 2))),
  # in addition, there is a day to day variation, e.g. in the raneg of 1/1.25 to 1.25 taht affects all readouts on that day
  day.to.day = as.data.frame(t(2^runif(n = r, min = log(x = 1/1.25, 2), max = log(x = 1.25, 2))), col.names = 1:5) # colnames does not work here
)
colnames(lSet$day.to.day) <- 1:5
dfSample <- data.frame(ID = 1:n)

for (readout in LETTERS[1:3]) { # readout in "A", "B", "C"
  for (replicate in 1:5) {
    dfSample[ , paste(readout, replicate, sep="")] <- # readout =
      lSet$base.level * lSet$factors[readout] *       #   factor for A, B, C  *
      unlist(lSet$day.to.day[replicate]) *            #   day to day variation *
      rnorm(n = n, mean = 1, sd = 0.1)                #   error for each individual measurement
  }
}

# some values are missing, i.e. for some persons only 4 days of measurement were possible:
dfSample[c(3, 8, 15), grep(pattern = "5", x = colnames(dfSample))] <- NA
```

I am sorry if this is too basic, but I got stuck and do not know where to search further and it does not fit in my standard textbook examples.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Could you include an example of your data? I'm having a hard time imagining what exactly you are comparing.

Comment: @FransRodenburg Thanks - I included a reproducible sample data set.